# How to query JSON Object to get the list

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have a JSON file like this:

```
 {
 "APIs": [
      {
        "name": "ALPHA.API01.10",
        "scope": "ALPHA",
        "service": "API01",
        "version": "1.0.0.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "ALPHA.API02.12",
        "scope": "ALPHA",
        "service": "API02",
        "version": "1.2.0.3"
      },
      {
        "name": "BETA.API01.10",
        "scope": "BETA",
        "service": "API01",
        "version": "1.0.0.0"
      },
      {
       "name": "BETA.API01.20",
       "scope": "BETA",
       "service": "API01",
       "version": "2.0.0.0"
      }
]}
```

I am trying to get the service name under the same scope. For example under scope ALPHA I want to get all the service name.

Here is my C# code for this:

```
public class APIs
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string scope { get; set; }
    public string service { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
}
public class APIObject
{
    public APIs[] APIs { get; set; }
}


JArray testArray = (JArray)jObject["APIs"];
var query = from testing in testArray
                select new APIs
                    {
                        scope = (string)testing["scope"],
                        service = (string)testing["service"],
                        version = (string)testing["version"]
                    };

List<APIs> testings = query.ToList() as List<APIs>;
var item = testings.Find(f => f.scope == "ALPHA");
```

With this code I can get the list of API within a list object. May I please get some better idea.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If you aren't I assume you're only getting the first in the list. This would because you're using `Find` in your last line of the sample. `Find` returns the first occurrence and `Where` would return all occurrences that meet your condition. So, try `Where` if you're not getting errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JSON.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

```
  var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIObject>(jsonString);
  var result = data.APIs.Where(x => x.scope == "ALPHA").Select(x => x.service).ToList();
```