# How to query a JSON array in a URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, url, postman

I have a JSON file that has an array of objects, I am trying to query where the `outcome` of an employee equals `Success`. What should the URL filter/query look like in this case? This is my URL `https://example.com/v1/employee/all`

```
    {
     "type": "Employees",
     "information": [
    {
        "name": "MarkSmith",
        "employeeId": 1,
        "details": {
            "salesHistory": [
                {
                    "sale": [
                        {
                            "outcome": "Success",
                            "numberOfDays": 5,
                            "saleType": "Phone"
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "JaneDoe",
        "employeeId": 15,
        "details": {
            "salesHistory": [
                {
                    "sale": [
                        {
                            "outcome": "Pending",
                            "numberOfDays": 2,
                            "saleType": "Online"
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ]
        }
    },
]
}
```

I have tried to query by `employeeId` like this -`https://example.com/v1/employee/all?type=Employees&information[][employeeId]=1` with no luck. Would be greatly appreciated if someone can provide me with some examples to learn this.

Comment: Without the API spec no one will be able to help you. If there is a way to query that data, it should be documented in the API.

Comment: Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58436877/how-to-query-json-object-to-get-the-list

Answer (score 0):

For such complex queries I'd suggest creating an OData Endpoint with Queries Enabled. This will take care of a lot of things for you. Take a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint